# Há limites no uso de operadores lógicos na consulta MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, select

Bom, gostaria de saber se existe limites em relação a quantidade de operadores lógicos que posso usar em uma consulta MySQL, por exemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = 'Fulano' OR email = 'email@email.com' AND id <> '1'";
```

Gostaria também de saber se esta consulta acima é válida.. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há limites de operadores, porém eles afetam diretamente no desempenho da consulta, inclusive na ordem em que são colocados.

A sua consulta é valida, porém pode não lhe trazer o resultado desejado pela ordem dos operadores. O `AND` sempre será processado primeiro que o `OR`, assim os resultados retornados pela consulta, tem o nome igual a 'Fulano' ou o email igual ao informado e id diferente de 1.

Para acertar esse problema, utilize parenteses para informar qual será processado primeiro, dessa forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE (nome = 'Fulano' OR email = 'email@email.com') AND id <> 1";
```

Se seu campo `id` é numérico, não é necessário que ele esteja entre aspas ('1') o banco terá que executar a conversão de texto para número desnecessariamente.

Ainda sobre os operadores, em lógica matemática o operador AND corresponde à multiplicação, e o OR à adição. Por isso da ordem, apenas matemática.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar quantos operadores forem necessários na sua consulta, não há limites, sendo que você pode melhorar as condições isolando cada uma colocando-as entre parênteses.

Seu exemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = 'Fulano' OR email = 'email@email.com' AND id <> '1'";
```

Pode não trazer o resultado desejado, o mais conveniente seria:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE (nome = 'Fulano') OR (email = 'email@email.com') AND (id <> 1)";
```

Assim como outro resultado poderia ser diferente (**poderia**, não é uma afirmação):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE (nome = 'Fulano' OR email = 'email@email.com') AND (id <> 1)";
```

O desempenho da sua consulta pode ser melhor se você começar pela condição menos provável.